# Only get_posts of certain post formats

Tags: php, archives, get-posts, post-formats

I'm trying to create a archive list with only my "normal" post format articles (not link, aside, quote, etc formats).

How would I implement `has_post_format( 'standard' )`, or something similar, into the code below?

I haven't been able to find a query for `get_posts` that only requests specific format types.

```
<?php    
    // Get the posts
    $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&orderby=post_date&order=DESC');     
?>

<?php foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>   

<?php    
    // Setup the post variables
    setup_postdata($post);

    $year = mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date);
    $month = mysql2date('n', $post->post_date);
    $day = mysql2date('j', $post->post_date);    
?>

<p>
    <span class="the_article">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </span>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span class="the_day">
        <?php the_time('j F Y'); ?>
    </span>
</p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My php skills are at the beginner level at best, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<del>You can't actually pass a taxonomy-related argument to [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).</del> **(Edit: actually, yes you can. The Codex is just somewhat unclear. Looking at source, `get_posts()` is, at its heart, just a wrapper for `WP_Query()`.)** You can pass meta keys/values, and post *types*, but not taxonomies such as post format. So for this line:

```
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&orderby=post_date&order=DESC');
```

I would recommend using [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) rather than `get_posts()`:

```
$myposts = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(                
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 
                'post-format-aside',
                'post-format-audio',
                'post-format-chat',
                'post-format-gallery',
                'post-format-image',
                'post-format-link',
                'post-format-quote',
                'post-format-status',
                'post-format-video'
            ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
) );
```

Note: yes, that's a lot of nested arrays. Tax queries can be tricky like that.

The next step is to modify your loop open/close statements. Change these:

```
<?php foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>

    <?php /* loop markup goes here */ ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

...to this:

```
<?php if ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : while ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : $myposts->the_post(); ?>

    <?php /* loop markup goes here */ ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Your actual loop markup *should* be able to remain the same, except that you no longer need to call `setup_postdata( $post )`:

```
<?php        
    $year = mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date);
    $month = mysql2date('n', $post->post_date);
    $day = mysql2date('j', $post->post_date);    
?>

<p>
    <span class="the_article">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </span>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span class="the_day">
        <?php the_time('j F Y'); ?>
    </span>
</p>
```

So, putting it all together:

```
<?php
// Only query posts with the
// "standard" post format, which
// requires *excluding* all other
// post formats, since neither the
// "post_format" taxonomy nor the
// "post-format-standard" taxonomy term
// is applied to posts without
// defined post formats
$myposts = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(                
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 
                'post-format-aside',
                'post-format-audio',
                'post-format-chat',
                'post-format-gallery',
                'post-format-image',
                'post-format-link',
                'post-format-quote',
                'post-format-status',
                'post-format-video'
            ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
) );

// Open the loop
if ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : while ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : $myposts->the_post(); ?>

    $year = mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date);
    $month = mysql2date('n', $post->post_date);
    $day = mysql2date('j', $post->post_date);    
    ?>

    <p>
        <span class="the_article">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class="the_day">
            <?php the_time('j F Y'); ?>
        </span>
    </p>  
    <?php 

// Close the loop
endwhile; endif;

// Reset $post data to default query
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: thanks, you made it really easy for a beginner to understand by breaking it down nicely. I'm guessing since I only use aside, link and standard post formats, I can actually skip the rest.

Comment: Yes; you would only need to include whichever post formats you've *enabled* support for.

Comment: get_posts() actually utilises WP_Query, so of course you can pass in taxonomy queries, just pass them as an array and not as a query string.

Comment: @shabushabu thanks for that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Post formats are just predefined terms in a taxonomy called `post_format`, so you should be able to use the WP template hierarchy to create post format archives. Just create a file called `taxonomy-post_format-post-format-standard.php` in the root of your theme and that file will be used to output all your standard posts. You can substitute 'standard' with any of the other format names, like `aside`, `link` or `video`, so e.g. `taxonomy-post_format-post-format-video.php`. This works for any other taxonomy as well, btw, as long as you stick to this format: `taxonomy-{TAXONOMY_NAME}-{TERM_NAME}.php`

If you want to show post formats with a custom loop, e.g. in your sidebar or within a page template, then you can use the tax query from @kaiser. Just substitute the taxonomy with `post_format` and the slugs with `post-format-{FORMAT_NAME}`.

Comment: thanks, but I'm trying to create the archives within a page template, so I'll go with one of the other solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

For two different taxonomies. For a single one, you can leave the `relation` arg out.

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_janner',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'action', 'commedy' ) // Single terms as string - multiple as array
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do trick like that:

```
<?php 
while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_post_format()==false? get_template_part( 'loop', 'posts' ) : false;
endwhile;
?>
```

It is because get_post_format() for standard post format returns false.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format

Comment: actually this does work, but you'll get into trouble, when you consider paging. if you do something like `'posts_per_page' => 6` and have 4 posts with NOT standard template, you will only see 2 posts, not the 6 that should be visible. filtering the query is the proof way to go..